# what is the param chunksize mean in python2 mutilprocessing pool map function?

Tags: function, dictionary, multiprocessing, pool

in python2, mutilprocessing pool function map, i set param 'chunksize=2' ,but it does not work. i confuse what that is mean? code as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import time
import os

work = [1,2,3,4,5,6]


def work_log(work_data):
    print "{} receive data: {}".format(os.getpid(), work_data)


def pool_handler():
    p = Pool(2)
    p.map(work_log, work,chunksize=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_handler()
```

i receive the res as follows:

25883 receive data: 1

25884 receive data: 3

25884 receive data: 4

25883 receive data: 2

25884 receive data: 5

25884 receive data: 6

the res should be : [1,2] , [ 3,4] , [5,6]

as the file mention:

map(func, iterable[, chunksize])

```
A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only one iterable argument though). It blocks until the result is ready.

This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.
```

Comment: i understand wrong  ,

test by set chunksize some value ，always there are process_num / chunksize worker woking

Comment: chunksize is a tuning parameter that determines how many  "tasks" are sent to each worker at a time. The process of sending the task is somewhat slow, so sending fewer, larger "tasks" may be faster in some instances than one "task" per loop iteration. It should not impact the output at all, but in some instances may improve performance.